# Need help to find correct Regex format

Tags: c#, regex

This is the string:

```
+CUSD: 1,"Your current Bank Account balance is Tk 17,370.37. Your available Bank Account balance is Tk 17,370.37.",15
```

the number beside cusd:, the account balance amounts, and the last digit, in this case 15 will all vary.

Is the following Regex format correct?

```
Match match = new Regex("\\+CUSD: (\\d+),\"Your current Bank Account balance is Tk (.+) Your available Bank Account balance is Tk (.+)\",(.+)\\r\\n").Match(input);
while (match.Success)
{do something;}
```

Comment: Yes. But delete final \\r\\n

Comment: Thanks for the reply, may I know what (.+) stands for? @VadimMartynov

Comment: `(.+)` would match one or more `+` of any character `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
@"\+CUSD: (\d+),""Your current Bank Account balance is Tk ([\d,.]+)\. Your available Bank Account balance is Tk ([\d.,]+)\."",(\d+)"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%2BCUSD%3A%20(%5Cd%2B)%2C%22Your%20current%20Bank%20Account%20balance%20is%20Tk%20(%5B%5Cd%2C.%5D%2B)%5C.%20Your%20available%20Bank%20Account%20balance%20is%20Tk%20(%5B%5Cd.%2C%5D%2B)%5C.%5C%22%2C(%5Cd%2B)&i=%2BCUSD%3A%201%2C%22Your%20current%20Bank%20Account%20balance%20is%20Tk%2017%2C370.37.%20Your%20available%20Bank%20Account%20balance%20is%20Tk%2017%2C370.37.%22%2C15)

[image]

Here, I suggest precising the `.+` as either `\d+` (1 or more digits) or `[\d.,]+` (matching 1+ digits, dots or periods). If you use `.+`, it matches 1+ characters other than a newline, and will cause lots of unnecessary backtracking that could slow down performance with long inputs.

Also, use raw string literals with `@"..."`, that way you do not have to use double escaping with special regex characters that should be treated as literals (e.g. `\+`), or with declaring shorthand character classes like `\d`.

Here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/sRrKGC):

```
var s = "+CUSD: 1,\"Your current Bank Account balance is Tk 17,370.37. Your available Bank Account balance is Tk 17,370.37.\",15";
var mtch = Regex.Match(s, @"\+CUSD: (\d+),""Your current Bank Account balance is Tk ([\d,.]+)\. Your available Bank Account balance is Tk ([\d.,]+)\."",(\d+)");
if (mtch.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CUSD: {0}", mtch.Groups[1].Value));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Bank Account balance: {0}", mtch.Groups[2].Value));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Your available Bank Account balance: {0}", mtch.Groups[3].Value));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Last number: {0}", mtch.Groups[4].Value));
}
```

Comment: what if the balance has 2 comas, such as 100,100,100.00?

Comment: That is [not a problem](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%2bCUSD%3a+(%5cd%2b)%2c%22Your+current+Bank+Account+balance+is+Tk+(%5b%5cd%2c.%5d%2b)%5c.+Your+available+Bank+Account+balance+is+Tk+(%5b%5cd.%2c%5d%2b)%5c.%5c%22%2c(%5cd%2b)&i=%2bCUSD%3a+1%2c%22Your+current+Bank+Account+balance+is+Tk+100%2c100%2c100.00.+Your+available+Bank+Account+balance+is+Tk+17%2c370.37.%22%2c15). If the first and last numbers can have `,` or `.`, just replace `\d+` with a character class like the one used to match the account balance.

Comment: what can I do to extract the balance in a string?

Comment: The last but one capture group (`$3` in the picture)? Right after `Your available Bank Account balance is Tk`?